# Eclipse CDT/Qt: have a Qt Gui project depend on another C++ project in the workspace

Tags: c++, qt, eclipse-cdt

I've implemented a rather complex algorithm in an Eclipse C++ project ("MyAlgorithm") using Eclipse/CDT. In order to be able to visualise the steps of the algorithm, I'd like to create a simple Qt GUI. I've downloaded and installed the Qt Eclipse integration and have created a Qt Project ("MyGUI") with a main window. Everything compiles like it should - the individual components are all in place.

However, when I try to use the classes from MyAlgorithm in MyGUI, everything grinds to a stop... Although I've referenced MyAlgorithm in MyGUI in all possible dialogs and places I can think of [1], building the project still fails with:

> main.cpp:5: fatal error: MyAlgorithmClass.h: No such file or directory

List of places where I've referenced MyAlgorithm in MyGUI (all in the project properties of "MyGUI"):

- C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols (using "Add Include Path from Workspace...")
- C/C++ Project Paths (tab "Projects", checked the "MyAlgorithm" project in list "Required projects on the build path"
- Project References, checked the "MyAlgorithm" project in list "Project references for 'MyGUI'"

Although the build process fails, the Eclipse/CDT auto-complete feature *does* suggest the existence of "MyAlgorithmClass.h" when I try to include it in the "MyGUI" project. I also noticed that changing the project settings (as described in the list above) does not trigger any changes in the Makefile.

Might it be the case that the Qt Eclipse integration prevents CDT from updating the Makefile accordingly, causing the build process to fail because of missing parameters to the compiler/linker?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that the QT-Eclipse integration does not work correctly. You need to manually update the QT .pro file for your project:

**Adding Libraries:**

Add any libs using syntax:

```
LIBS += -L<Full path to library include directory>
LIBS += -l<Eclipse Artifact>
```

example:

```
LIBS += -LC:/MyEclipseWorkspace/Project1/Debug
LIBS += -lProject1
```

This will link libProject1.a into your eclipse project.

**Adding Include Files:**

```
INCLUDEPATH += <Absolute or Relative Path to include location>
```

example:

```
INCLUDEPATH += src ../Project2/include C:/dev/boost_1_46_1
```

HTH